# Insert values into database with foreign key using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with the following issue:
I have two tables:

```
category table:
category_id     |      category_name
```

---

```
brand table
brand_id     |      brand_name     |      category_id (FOREIGN KEY)
```

I was trying to insert a new brand name value using PHP with FOREIGN KEY that referenced to `category id`.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO brand (category_id, brand_name) VALUES('$category_name','$brand')";
```

However it could not be added into the brand table.

Comment: Are you inserting category_name as value for category_id ? You should insert the category_id and make sure the id is present in the category table.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes i am trying to get the category_name  fetched from my DB category table and insert it to the brand table. each brand name are pointing base to the selected category_name .

Comment: As has been pointed out, you have to insert the `category_id` into the `brand` table. When you want to retrieve data from the `brand` table, you can get the category name by using a query such as `SELECT brand_name, category_name FROM brand b JOIN category c ON c.category_id=b.category_id`

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key means category_id in table brand is refer to the same category_id in table category, so the category_id inserted in table brand must exist in table category.

When you insert new record in table brand, you need to insert the ID (not the category name) and make sure that id is exist in table category

Comment: Thank you very much, now I am able to insert new brand(value) to my database. but Is there any option to select the category_name instead of category_id. the scenario is I am trying to add new brand name reference to the category name inside the select tag that fetch from the category table,.